# How can I prevent the posts of friends of Friends from showing up in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

How can I prevent the posts of friends of Friends in Facebook? I really don't care to see all the garbage some of these people post.

Answer (score 4):

Posts by Friends of Friends will not normally appear in your News Feed unless one of your friends (or someone that you subscribe to) comments on or likes the post, and the post is visible to you.

If some of your friends (or subscriptions) frequently comment on or like posts that you do not want to see, hover over one of those posts in your News Feed, click on the **∨** that appears in the upper right corner of the post, then click **Unsubscribe from comments and likes by _______**.

Then you will no longer see posts in your News Feed just because that person commented on or liked the post.

[image: Unsubscribe from comments and likes]

Also make sure that you are not "Subscribed" to the "Friends of Friends" you are talking about.

Comment: This answer seems right, and I confirm I am not supposed to get likes and comments from certain friends. However, I still see their likes in my news feed after some time.

Answer (score 1):

I am observing the same thing while other friends are NOT seeing it. I suspect we might be part of one of Facebook's A/B tests.

[image: Shot of a friend of a friend's post showing up in my newsfeed. Who is Pinky Bixter Pie or Lisa Giesick? I have no idea.]

Yes, I totally care that your crazy cousin from Fresno shared a link to a Awesome Formula One video.

Oh and I see your coworker wants you to like the new Nissan Stanza. I'm glad I didn't miss that important event in your life.

It amounts to random people I don't know and don't even like posting in MY feed. That sure seems like a good feature.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The OP has asked how to prevent this, not whether it's happening.